# Reuse graph, and use it multiple times

Tags: tensorflow

I was toying around with style transfer. An important part is re-using an existing model. Currently I import the vgg graph like this:

```
net = vgg16.get_vgg_model()
name_layer = 'conv2_2/conv2_2:0'
feature_transformed_image = tf.import_graph_def(
        net['graph_def'],
        name='vgg',
        input_map={'images:0': image},return_elements=[name_layer])
```

Now I would like to re-use the vgg model multiple times (as I need to get the output for multiple images).

Unfortunately, running this piece of code multiple times makes me import the whole graph again multiple times (waste of RAM and time).

So my question is: how can I import this graph once, and re-use it with multiple inputs.

Comment: You can pass any Tensor to be replaced in a `feed_dict` argument to `session.run` (not just explicit `placeholder`s). Can you import the graph once, then `run` it multiple times feeding different images?

Comment: Dear Allen, Thank you very much for your reply, I did not know this was possible! Unfortunately, in this case I would like to calculate the content loss in my graph for several images... Using session.run for each of the images means I cant compute the loss in the graph itself...

Comment: You might look into [tf.contrib.learn Estimators](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/estimators/#constructing_the_model_fn), which have a notion of evaluation metrics which accumulate information across graph executions (the principle is simple enough, just using Variables as accumulators, but perhaps they have a pre-made accumulator you could use).